# Return a previous function inside function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consist of two columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country":['Taiwan', 'Malaysia', 'Taiwan', 'Taiwan', 'Malaysia'], 'Rating':[10, 9, 0, 5, 7]})
```

I made the first function to return the difference of rating between the two countries.

```
def difference_of_rating_average(dataframe, column_name="Country"):
    taiwan = []
    malaysia = []
    for index , row in taiwan_and_malaysia.iterrows():
      if row[column_name] == "Taiwan":
        taiwan.append(row["Stars"])
      else:
        malaysia.append(row["Stars"])
    return abs((sum(taiwan)/len(taiwan)) - (sum(malaysia)/len(malaysia)))
```

Then I make the second function with dataframe as input parameter. The second function would make an additional column, named "Shuffle", which contains the shuffled data of Country column in the input dataframe. In the end, the second function is expected to return the first function with input of dataframe and "Shuffle" column.

```
def one_simulated_difference(table):
    table1 = pd.concat([table["Country"],table["Stars"]],axis=1,keys=['Country','Stars'])
    shuffled_labels = table1["Country"].sample(frac=1).values

    shuffled_table = table1
    shuffled_table["Shuffle"] = shuffled_labels
    return difference_of_rating_average(table1,"Shuffle")
```

However, when I run the second function, I got an error:

```
KeyError: 'Shuffle'
```

Which probably means the first function doesn't recognize the "Shuffle" column resulted from the the second function. I have check the name, upper and lower case, and all just fine.
What is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to do

```
for index , row in dataframe.iterrows():
```

rather than

```
for index , row in taiwan_and_malaysia.iterrows():
```

It looks like you are trying to iterate through a different table than the one you provide as an argument.